# Why do I get syntax errors when I deploy capistrano?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm new with capistrano and ruby and when I use `cap deploy`, I get some errors. I've tried to upgrade my ruby version and `io-console`, but none of them helped me to resolve my problem. Could someone help me resolving it?

Below my error log:

````
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      super(<<~MESSAGE)
              ^
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_in, expecting keyword_end
...hod is meant to display text in the user locale, so calling ...
...                               ^
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
... in the user locale, so calling it before the user locale has
...                               ^
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...tside of the user flow, you can do so by passing
...                               ^
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...ctly with the `locale` argument, e.g. `I18n.#{method}(..., l...
...                               ^
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting :: or '[' or '.'
...e `locale` argument, e.g. `I18n.#{method}(..., locale: :en)`
...                               ^
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/i18n-1.6.0/lib/i18n.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/all.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/bin/cap:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'```
````

Comment: _"I've tried to upgrade my ruby version"_ – maybe it's a problem with your server's Ruby version. Does `cap deploy` exit right away or does the error occur during deployment? The latter would indicate a problem on the remote side.

Comment: What do you try to deploy? A Ruby on Rails application? Do you use Bundler? Does your application include a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? Did update Ruby on your development computer? And on the server?

Answer (score 4):

The path of your error message looks like you are using Ruby `2.0` and version `1.6.0` of the `i18n` gem. The `i18n` gem uses the squiggly heredoc syntax (`<<~`) in that version. The syntax was introduced in Ruby 2.3.

That means you have two options:

- Update your Ruby version to at least 2.3 *or*
- downgrade the `i18n`. [`1.5.1`](https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions/1.5.1) seems to be the latest version that doesn't depend on Ruby 2.3

Comment: Hello, the problem that i am using ruby 2.4. when i launch `ruby -v` i've got `ruby 2.4.5p335`

Comment: Try downgrading your i18n gem to 1.5.1, should remove the invalid syntax

Comment: i use `gem uninstall i18n` and after `gem install i18n -v 1.5.1` and i still got same error

Comment: What version is in your gemfile? This is the version that capistrano will use